# How do I get table row data in another table when I tic on same row checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in which 4 fields are service, amount, tax, action.
The question is when I check the checkbox in any row, the same row data also been adding in the second table with table fields like service, amount, tax, action.
But I want to remove the last field like action in the second table.
**Here is my code below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="table1" rules="all" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Service</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">tax</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class='servicetr'>
                <td class="service"><span>Subscription Charges</span></td>
                <td><span>500.00</span></td>
                <td class="service"><span>90.00</span></td>
                <td><input class="tot_amount" data-toggle="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="590.00"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='servicetr'>
                <td><span>registration fees</span></td>
                <td><span>200.00</span></td>
                <td><span>80.00</span></td>
                <td><input class="tot_amount" data-toggle="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="590.00"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="table2" rules="all" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Service</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">tax</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){  
         if (this.checked){  


             var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
             $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr class='servicetr'>" + $tr.html() + "<\/tr>");
         }  
         else{
          var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");  
          $('#table2').find(".servicetr").each(function(){    
            if($tr.html() == $(this).html())
            $(this).remove();  
          });

         }
         });
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".tot_amount", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $trClass = $(this).closest("tr").attr("class");
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr class='"+ $trClass +"'>" + $tr.html() + "</tr>");
      $("#table2 tbody").find('input').parent().remove();
    } else {
     
      $('#table2').find(".servicetr").each(function() {
        if($tr.hasClass("subscription")){
         $("#table2").find(".subscription").remove();
        } else if($tr.hasClass("registration")){
         $("#table2").find(".registration").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Service </th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">tax</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class='servicetr subscription'>
      <td class="service">
        <span>Subscription Charges</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>500.00</span>
      </td>
      <td class="service">
        <span>90.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='servicetr registration'>
      <td>
        <span>registration fees</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>200.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>80.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Service </th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">tax</th>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it; using `data-id` to identify the row to be removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){  
    if (this.checked){  
      var $tr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
      $tr.find("td").last().remove();
      $("#table2 tbody").append($tr);
    } else {
      var $trid = $(this).closest("tr").data('id');  
      $('#table2').find(".servicetr[data-id='" + $trid + "']").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>table</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Service </th>
          <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          <th scope="col">tax</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class='servicetr' data-id="1">
          <td class="service">
            <span>Subscription Charges</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>500.00</span>
          </td>
          <td class="service">
            <span >90.00</span>
          </td>
          <td >
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class='servicetr' data-id="2">
        <td>
          <span>registration fees</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>200.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span >80.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Service </th>
          <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          <th scope="col">tax</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```